# Unique variable names in Z3

Tags: variables, z3

I need to rely on the fact that two Z3 variables
can **not** have the same name.
To be sure of that,
I've used [tuple_example1()](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c/test_capi.c#L1294) from [test_capi.c](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c/test_capi.c) in [z3/examples/c](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/master/examples/c) and changed the original code from:

```
// some code before that ...
x    = mk_real_var(ctx, "x");
y    = mk_real_var(ctx, "y"); // originally y is called "y"
// some code after that ...
```

to:

```
// some code before that ...
x    = mk_real_var(ctx, "x");
y    = mk_real_var(ctx, "x"); // but now both x and y are called "x"
// some code after that ...
```

And (as expected) the output changed from:

```
tuple_example1
tuple_sort: (real, real)
prove: get_x(mk_pair(x, y)) = 1 implies x = 1
valid
disprove: get_x(mk_pair(x, y)) = 1 implies y = 1
invalid
counterexample:
y -> 0.0
x -> 1.0
```

to:

```
tuple_example1
tuple_sort: (real, real)
prove: get_x(mk_pair(x, y)) = 1 implies x = 1
valid
disprove: get_x(mk_pair(x, y)) = 1 implies y = 1
valid
BUG: unexpected result.
```

However, when I looked closer, I found out that Z3 did not really fail or anything, it is just a naive (driver) print out to console.
So I went ahead and wrote the **exact same test with y being an int sort called "x"**.
To my surprise, Z3 could handle **two variables** with the **same name** when they have different sorts:

```
tuple_example1
tuple_sort: (real, real)
prove: get_x(mk_pair(x, y)) = 1 implies x = 1
valid
disprove: get_x(mk_pair(x, y)) = 1 implies y = 1
invalid
counterexample:
x -> 1.0
x -> 0
```

Is that really what's going on? or is it just a coincidence?? 
Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, SMT-Lib does allow repeated variable names, so long as they have different sorts. See page 27 of [the standard](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf). In particular, it says:

> Concretely, a variable can be any symbol, while a function symbol
>   can be any identifier (i.e., a symbol or an indexed symbol). As a
>   consequence, contextual information is needed during parsing to know
>   whether an identifier is to be treated as a variable or a function
>   symbol. For variables, this information is provided by the three
>   binders which are the only mechanism to introduce variables. Function
>   symbols, in contrast, are predefined, as explained later. Recall that
>   every function symbol f is separately associated with one or more
>   ranks, each specifying the sorts of f’s arguments and result. To
>   simplify sort checking, a function symbol in a term can be annotated
>   with one of its result sorts σ. Such an annotated function symbol is a
>   qualified identifier of the form (as f σ).

Also on page 31 of the same document, it further clarifies "ambiguity" thusly:

> Except for patterns in match expressions, every occurrence of an
>   ambiguous function symbol f in a term must occur as a qualified
>   identifier of the form (as f σ) where σ is the intended output sort of
>   that occurrence

So, in SMT-Lib lingo, you'd write like this:

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun x () Real)

(assert (= (as x Real) 2.5))
(assert (= (as x Int) 2))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

This produces:

```
sat
(model
  (define-fun x () Int
    2)
  (define-fun x () Real
    (/ 5.0 2.0))
)
```

What you are observing in the C-interface is essentially a rendering of the same. Of course, how much "checking" is enforced by the interface is totally solver specific as SMT-Lib says nothing about C API's or API's for other languages. That actually explains the `BUG` line you see in the output there. At this point, the behavior is entirely solver specific.

But long story short, SMT-Lib does indeed allow two variables have the same name used so long as they have different sorts.